# Join one to many models with sum using eloquent on laravel

Tags: laravel-5, model, eloquent, relationships

below work fine but I want to change it to two models(one to many relationship)
how can I write the query?

```php
$results=
Big::query()
->      select('A.id','A.product')
        ->addSelect(DB::raw('SUM(CASE WHEN B.approve = 1 THEN 1 
                                      WHEN B.approve = -1 THEN -1 ELSE 0 END) as approveshow'))                              
        ->from('Bigs as A')
        ->leftjoin('Smaills as B', function($join) {
            $join->on('A.ID', '=', 'B.p_id');
            })
        ->groupBy('A.id','A.product')
        ->whereIn('A.id',$wantids)
        ->get();
```

I write the model like this
~~~Model Big~~~

```php
class Big extends Model
{
       public function smalls()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Big','p_id','id');
    }
}
```

~~~Model Small~~~

```php
class Small extends Model
{
    public function big()
    {                   
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Big','p_id','id');
    }
}
```

how can I join two models using eloquent and use  sum raw function?

like

```php
$results=Big::whereIn('id',$wantids)->smalls  ....?;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a modified `withCount()` and shorten the `SUM` expression a bit:

```php
Big::select('id','product')
    ->withCount(['smalls as approveshow' => function($query) {
        $query->select(DB::raw('SUM(CASE WHEN approve IN (-1, 1) THEN approve ELSE 0 END'));
    }])
    ->whereIn('id', $wantids)
    ->get();
```

Comment: thanks~But I want to know how to use two models and  eloquent method .

Comment: Do you mean without any raw SQL? That's not possible.

Comment: So just use my original query builder is almost the same with the eloquent as they all need DB raw SQL?~I thought the model has more convenient way ,as last it's just a little concise.